# How can I add entity to relation only with ID without fetching it?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, typeorm

I am creating a Many-To-Many relation

```
@Entity({
    name: 'product'
})
export class Product {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column({type: 'decimal', precision: 13, scale: 2})
    price: number;

    @ManyToMany(() => Tag, (tag: Tag) => tag.products)
    @JoinTable({
        name: 'product_tag'
    })
    tags: Tag[];

    @CreateDateColumn()
    createdAt: Timestamp;

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updatedAt: Timestamp;
}
```

```
@Entity({
    name: 'tag'
})
export class Tag {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @ManyToMany(() => Product, (product: Product) => product.tags)
    products: Product[];

    @CreateDateColumn()
    createdAt: Timestamp;

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updatedAt: Timestamp;
}
```

let say there is some tag in db . eg: `Tag = [{id: 1, name: 'pc'}, {id: 2, name: 'laptop'}]`

And I have product `Product = [{id: 1, name: 'Zenbook', price: 10000 }]`

Now  I need to add those tags to the product.

I wanted do something  like this

```
const product = await this.repository.findOne({id: 1});

product.tags = [{id: 1}, {id:2}];

await this.repository.save(product);
```

I know this is wrong.

How can I do this?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I had this question too and it took some digging but I found [Working with Relations](https://typeorm.io/#/relational-query-builder) in the TypeORM docs

For your situation you want

```js
await getConnection()
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .relation(Product, "tags")
    .of(product)
    /**
     * Adds (binds) given value to entity relation.
     * Value can be entity, entity id or entity id map (if entity has composite ids).
     * Value also can be array of entities, array of entity ids or array of entity id maps (if entity has composite ids).
     * Works only for many-to-many and one-to-many relations.
     * For many-to-one and one-to-one use #set method instead.
     */
    .add([1, 2]);
```